# How to create a custom admin notification

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, adminnotification

I want to create a custom admin notification message for a module im developing like the one on the image below. I want the notification to remain visible in all admin pages until a certain condition has been met.

[image]

There is another [thread](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106710/how-to-create-custom-sticky-admin-system-messages/107725#107725) on this subject but i couldn't find how to get the model class that implements **\Magento\Framework\Notification\MessageInterface** to be executed. The thread author mentioned that a dependency to Magento_AdminNotification is needed.

Is that achieved on the di.xml file? A more detailed explanation would be very helpful.

Comment: I found that adding `<item name="className" xsi:type="string">VendorName\ModuleName\Model\ClassName</item>`to module-admin-notification's di.xml will get the notification to show up. But i want the code to be self contained in my module directory since i want my module to be distributed to other people.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. I was writing the di.xml file on the wrong directory.

To get your module's custom notification class to run, you need to create the file `VendorName/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml/di.xml` with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Notification\MessageList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="messages" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="yourClassName" xsi:type="string">VendorName\ModuleName\Model\System\Message\YourClassName</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Then you have to create the `VendorName\ModuleName\Model\System\Message\YourClassName.php` class file with the following code:

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Model\System\Message;

class YourClassName implements \Magento\Framework\Notification\MessageInterface
{

    public function getIdentity()
    {
        // Retrieve unique message identity
        return 'identity';
    }

    public function isDisplayed()
    {
        // Return true to show your message, false to hide it
        return true;
    }

    public function getText()
    {
        // Retrieve message text
        return 'Notification message text goes here';
    }

    public function getSeverity()
    {
        // Possible values: SEVERITY_CRITICAL, SEVERITY_MAJOR, SEVERITY_MINOR, SEVERITY_NOTICE
        return self::SEVERITY_MAJOR;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Daniel, I need to understand how to trigger this message, i want to send a notification on some condition in my module.

Comment: @Daniel  I have tried code but not working in magento 2.2.6

Comment: @Daniel what about if we want to add multiple notification using single file

Answer (score 1):

> Ktpl/Ordermanagement/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <type name="Magento\Framework\Notification\MessageList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="messages" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="user_view_count" xsi:type="string">Ktpl\Ordermanagement\Model\System\Message\Userviewcount</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

> Ktpl\Ordermanagement\Model\System\Message\Userviewcount.php

```
<?php

namespace Ktpl\Ordermanagement\Model\System\Message;

class Userviewcount implements \Magento\Framework\Notification\MessageInterface
{

    /**
    * Message identity
    */
   const MESSAGE_IDENTITY = 'custom_system_message';

   /**
    * Retrieve unique system message identity
    *
    * @return string
    */
   public function getIdentity()
   {
       return md5(self::MESSAGE_IDENTITY);
   }

   /**
    * Check whether the system message should be shown
    *
    * @return bool
    */
   public function isDisplayed()
   {
       // The message will be shown
       return true;
   }

   /**
    * Retrieve system message text
    *
    * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
    */
   public function getText()
   {
       return __('System Message Text.');
   }

   /**
    * Retrieve system message severity
    * Possible default system message types:
    * - MessageInterface::SEVERITY_CRITICAL
    * - MessageInterface::SEVERITY_MAJOR
    * - MessageInterface::SEVERITY_MINOR
    * - MessageInterface::SEVERITY_NOTICE
    *
    * @return int
    */
   public function getSeverity()
   {
       return self::SEVERITY_MAJOR;
   }
}
```